# PageSize greater than 100 with Backendless Standalone

Tags: backendless

Backendless Standalone does not have the [limits](https://backendless.com/products/pro/) of the hosted version. But when I try to return more than 100 records, I get the following error:

https://foo.com/api/v1/data/Product?pageSize=200

```
{
  "code": 1025,
  "message": "Invalid pagesize. Page size cannot be greater than 100."
}
```

How do you configure standalone to allow returning more than 100 records?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Unfortunately I think that Backendless server has the limit of 100, from the [documentation](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_data_paging.htm):

> Backendless server sets the maximum allowed value for the page size to
>   100 objects. The minimum value is 1.

To solve it I used a loop of calls regulating each loop the offset.

Hoping it has been helpful,

Gabriele

Comment: I think the cloud version has a hard limit of 100. The 3.0 standalone version also has a hard limit of 100. The 3.5+ standalone (Pro) can be configured to  ustomize maximum page size for paged data retrieval. The default value is 100 objects. It can be modified in a configuration file located <installdir>/apps/backendless/htdocs/conf/pagesize.properties. Make sure to restart all Backendless Pro processes after changing the default maximum page size. From https://backendless.com/documentation/backendlesspro/st_changing_default_limits.htm .

Comment: Also, some of the SDK check for the 100 limit, so you need to remove them from the SDK. for example the JS SDK has this in it: But the JS SDK also checks for the limit, so you have to remove that too. I am not sure about the other SDK.  DataStore.prototype = {
        _extractQueryOptions: function(options) {
            var params = [];

            if (typeof options.pageSize != 'undefined') {
                if (options.pageSize < 1 || options.pageSize > 100) {
                    throw new Error('PageSize can not be less then 1 or greater than 100');
                }